# TreeView from a SELF-JOINED table

Tags: java, javafx

Please help, I could not find an example anywhere. How to do in Java as in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2754/Populate-a-TreeView-from-a-SELF-JOINED-table) example, or something similar. I will be grateful for any help.

I have some tables [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkplv.jpg)
How to make TreeView like

```
Root(someText)
======First(Equipment)
============FirstProduct(Product)
========================FirstComponent (ComponentProduct)
==============================FirstDetail(Detail)
====================================FirstDetailDocument(Document)
==============================FirstComponentDocument(Document)
========================SecondComponent(ComponentProduct)
==============================SecondComponentDocument(Document)
==================FirstProductDocument(Document)
======Second(Equipment)
============SecondProduct(Product)
==================SecondProductDocument(Document)
======Third (Equipment)
============ThirdProduct (Product)
==================ThirdProductDocument(Document)
```

And download data from self-join database

Comment: Try to explain the problem instead of directing to an outside URL

Comment: What is the "path" from document to root? For the first leaf it seems like `document -> Detail -> ComponentProduct -> Product -> Equipment -> Root` but later `Detail` and in the end even `Detail` and `ComponentProduct` are missing. Also the diagram does not indicate a possible self-join anywhere.